# Server 2008 - Multiple Event 55 NTFS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, hard-drive

VMware ESXi with a virtual server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Event Viewer Administrative Events logs are flooded with the following error:

```
Event 55, Ntfs
The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. 
Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \Device\HarddiskVolume2.
```

I have run chkdsk /f to scan the disk on reboot, but looking at the Application event logs the scan does not appear to happen.

Are there any other potential fixes for this issue?

Comment: Did you watch the reboot to confirm whether chkdsk runs or not? Saying that it doesn't appear to run and knowing that it doesn't run are two different things. I'd rather know then assume.

Comment: chkdsk certainly doesn't run when restarting. I get this error - "Autochk cannot run due to an error caused by a recently installed software package". I removed the antivirus software as recommended by some sites, but the error still appears on boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check VMFS for metadata inconsistency, it's done with VMware Ondisk Metadata Analyser

Before you start VOMA from the CLI of your ESXi host, take care of the following guidelines:

Shut down all virtual machines running on the VMFS datastore

make sure that the VMFS volume is not in use by other hosts (best practice: unmount the datastore on the other hosts)

make sure that the datastore is not in use by vSphere HA for heartbeating

make sure that the datastore is not in use by other features like Storage I/O control,…

make sure that the volume is not a multi-extent volume

log on to your ESXi host (ssh) and run:

1) esxcfg-scsidevs -m will identify the naa -> datastorename mappings.

2) voma -m vmfs -f check -d /vmfs/volumes/NAA_OF_YOUR_DATASTORE:YOUR_PARTITION_NUMBER

The tool can only find errors – but not fix them.